# Explain why the following statements are logically equivalent (2 examples)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have the following 2 separate statements.
**(pvq)-> q = ~(p^~q)**
**r->(~pvq)=(pvr)->q**

I have proved they are both equivalent with a truth table, but I am asked to briefly explain (in words not with a theorem chart) why they are equivalent, and I have no idea why they are. I have looked at the Laws of Algebra of Propositions and they don't really address more 'complex' statements. Could I have some help and maybe someone knows of a more advanced chart (or I will learn to extrapolate better)

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any example that explain why 2 propositions are equivalent? It is better if it is an easy example so we can understand how you need to answer the question and help you better. Also, please use MathJax to render math correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The first equivalence can be proven as follows:
\begin{align*}
(p\vee q)\rightarrow q & \Longleftrightarrow (\neg(p\vee q))\vee q\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (\neg p\wedge\neg q)\vee q\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (\neg p\vee q)\wedge(\neg q\vee q)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \neg p\vee q\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \neg(p\wedge\neg q)
\end{align*}

The second equivalence can be proven as follows:
\begin{align*}
r\to(\neg p\vee q) & \Longleftrightarrow \neg r\vee(\neg p\vee q)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (\neg p\vee\neg r)\vee q\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (\neg(p\wedge r))\vee q\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (p\wedge r)\to q
\end{align*}

and we are done. Please let me know if my interpretation of the second equivalence is correct, since the obtained result is different.

Comment: I need to briefly describe in words why they are equivalent. Thank you for breaking it down that way but the assignment states 'briefly describe why they are equivalent'

Answer (score 0):

For the first: You are given (p or q) -> q.

Suppose that p and not q. Then p is true, because both are true, so p or q is true, because at least one of them is. But by the given implication, this implies q. But we assumed not q. Thus we must have *not* "p and not q."

For the second: You are given r -> ((not p) or q)

Suppose that p and r. Since r, we have not p and/or q. But we don't have not p, we have p! Thus we have q, because we must have at least one of not p or q, and we don't have not p. Which is what we wanted to implicate, q.

Hope this suffices